# Show All and Count Duplicates MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have this table:

```
id   name  
1    AAA
2    BBB
3    BBB
4    BBB
5    AAA
6    CCC
```

How can I get this?

```
id   name  count
1    AAA     2
2    BBB     3
3    BBB     3
4    BBB     3
5    AAA     2
6    CCC     1
```

I want to count duplicates(name), getting all rows, WITHOUT grouping it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id, name, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM mytable AS t1
                  WHERE t1.name = t2.name) AS cnt
FROM mytable AS t2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c7a9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.cnt
from your_table t1
join
(
  select name, count(*) as cnt
  from your_table
  group by name
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM demo AS table1
                  WHERE table1.name = table2.name) 
    AS count
FROM demo AS t2
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is a duplicate answer.